# Sequelize - Error: Named bind parameter "$123" has no value in the given object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

`Error: Named bind parameter "$123" has no value in the given object.`

Using the **Sequelize**, It is working for the normal/simple password. But when it comes to complicated passwords then it is throwing the above error.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: I think you need to explre [this](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11533#issuecomment-725284467)